# Returning Image from Query

Tags: apex, visualforce, document

I have a query fetching a document which is an image.  I want to assign the image to a field (URL).

I am doing:

```
Document doc = [select id, name,url, body from Document where name = 'image'];
Object.URLFIELD__c = doc.url;
```

However the image is always broken. I set it available for external use.

Is there a good way to reference the image in visualforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+doc.id

> Description
>   This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000113345&language=en_US) will help  to show an image into the visual
>   force page from the attachment object or document.
>
> Resolution
>   The image can be displayed in the VF page by using  tag. Image source is specified by "URL" attribute. But the url
>   should be in the form : "
>   /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=xxxxxxxxxxx" where  xxxxxxxxxxx is
>   the the unique id of theDocument/Attachment record containing the
>   image.